# Use xpathSApply in R

Tags: r

I would like to get the information of href from below.

http://www.mitbbs.com/bbsdoc1/USANews_101_0.html

I prefer to get someting from each topic like this

/USANews/31587637.html

/USANews/31587633.html

/USANews/31587631.html

...

The code is used below, but it doesn't work.

```
library("XML")   
library("httr")
library("stringr")

data <- list()

for( i in 101:201){
url <- paste('bbsdoc1/USANews_', i, '_0.html', sep='')
html <- content(GET("http://www.mitbbs.com/", path = url),as = 'parsed')
url.list <- xpathSApply(html, "//td[@align='left' height=26]/[@class='news1' href]", xmlAttrs)
data <- rbind(data, url.list)

}
```

Your suggestions are really appreicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the document

```
library(XML)
html = htmlParse("http://www.mitbbs.com/bbsdoc1/USANews_101_0.html")
```

and extract the links and text you're interested in using the appropriate xpath query

```
href = "//a[./@class='news1']/@href"
text = "//a[./@class='news1']/text()"
df = data.frame(
    url=sub("article_t/", "", sapply(html[href], as.character)),
    text=trimws(sapply(html[text], xmlValue)))
```

`trimws()` is a function in recent versions of R.

Comment: I would like to know why the code below does not work.

Comment: library(XML)
library(httr)
url <- "http://www.mitbbs.com/bbsdoc1/USANews_101_0.html/"
hrefs <- list()
for (i in 1:5) {
  response <- GET(paste0(url,i))
  doc      <- content(response,type="text/html")
  hrefs    <- c(hrefs,doc["a[./@class='news1']/@href"])
}

where i=1 for page 1 with 100 hrefs, i=2 for the 2nd page with another 100 hrefs,..., i=5 for the 5th page with another 100 hrefs. So that there should be a 5 x 100 hrefs.  I wonder how to get 100 hrefs in your way at one time. Thank you.

Comment: your `paste0(url, i)` leads to "mitbbs.com/bbsdoc1/USANews_101_0.html/1" but this page does not exist (the response includes " <header><h1>The page you are looking for cannot be found.</h1>") so I guess that's why you are having difficulties.

Comment: Is that `trimws` missing a couple of `""` items? `trimws = function(x)
     sub("[ \t\r\n]+$", "", sub("^[ \t\r\n]+", "", x))` perhaps?

Comment: @42- yep something is wrong, but since `trimws()` is now in release R, I removed the function definition.

Comment: It defines a helper function that had the `""` for the replacement argument and then uses choices of patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the rvest package which simplifies things a lot

```
library(rvest); library(dplyr)
myList <- read_html("http://www.mitbbs.com/bbsdoc1/USANews_101_0.html") %>% 
                html_nodes(".news1") %>% xml_attr("href")
mtList

myList %>% gsub("/article_t", "", .)
```

Comment: I got a deprecation warning and advice to change, so I upvoted and edited.