# R question: use xmlValue in xpathSApply, but get an empty list

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, httr

I'm attempting web scraping. Before posting my question, I looked up several similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814454/use-xpathsapply-in-r), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675626/web-scraping-with-xpathsapply-getting-xmlvalue). However, I still get stuck in my problem.

Speicifically, I'm trying to extract the listed prices on a [second-hand cars website](https://www.sahibinden.com/vasita?query_text_mf=alfa+romeo+giulietta&query_text=alfa+romeo+giulietta). # In case you are unable to see the data because you're not a registered user of this website, I also attached the screenshot of this website's html elements:
[the screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRvk0.jpg)
The code I executed are:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

url <- "https://www.sahibinden.com/vasita?query_text_mf=alfa+romeo+giulietta&query_text=alfa+romeo+giulietta"

htmlresponse <- GET(url)

htmlcontent <- content(htmlresponse, as="text")

parsedhtml <- htmlParse(htmlcontent, asText = TRUE)
# The above is just following the conventions, and seems okay.

prices <- xpathSApply(doc = parsedhtml, path = "//div/td[@class='searchResultsPriceValue']", fun = xmlValue)
# This command returned me an empty list.
```

Can someone have a look and give me some advices? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Xiao Lu. If you look at the html you get in R when you request this url, (i.e. if you look at `parsedhtml` you will see that the body of the html doesn't contain the div you want. Instead, it contains Javascript, which runs in your browser to create the document. That's the html you see in your developer panel. It seems the site runs this way to prevent people doing low-level web scraping. You could get round this using RSelenium, but I would check the site's terms and conditions to make sure this is allowed first.

Comment: Hi, Allan. Thanks for your suggestion. I guess it partially explains my confusion: I was doing well with the practices from online courses (they don't contain java script), but always ran into trouble when retrieving real-world data.